# Auth0 Lock - We're sorry something went wrong when attempting to log in

Tags: authentication, auth0, auth0-lock

I commented this problem on the following thread for an active issue regarding Auth0 lock, but wanted to ask here for more reach in case anyone else has experienced this.

From what I've researched, it seems that many people are having this issue, and it doesn't seem like there's a known explanation to what's going on.

The unfortunate thing is that this is happening to end users, and from what I have seen devs have not been able to reproduce this error.

https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/1838#issuecomment-918434321

#### Description

- User is able to view our Auth0 Lock
- User is not able to successfully sign up
- We created an account for them in Auth0 directly and are able to log in using credentials we created for them via the Lock
- User is not able to log in using the credentials and is shown the "We're sorry something went wrong when attempting to log in message"
- Auth0 logs don't actually show this user's attempts/errors when logging in

#### Reproduction

- Unable to reproduce locally, but trying everything we can to do so, including blocking all cookies (not the problem)
- Attempting to get any console warnings from the user as well

#### Environment

- Lock version: 11.30.4
- React Version: 17.0.2
- Next.js Version: 11.1.0
- Chrome 91, Windows